# c++ vsnprintf error when processing a long string(or strange)

Tags: c++, string, printf

What is the problem in this piece of code:

```
std::string StringPrintf(const char* fmt, ...) {
  int size = 512;
  char* buffer = new char[size];
  va_list vl; 
  va_start(vl, fmt);
  int nsize = vsnprintf(buffer, size, fmt, vl);

  if (size <= nsize) {  //fail delete buffer and try again
    delete[] buffer;
    buffer = 0;
    buffer = new char[nsize + 1];  //+1 for /0
    nsize = vsnprintf(buffer, size, fmt, vl);
  }
  std::string ret(buffer);
  va_end(vl);
  delete[] buffer;
  return ret;
}
```

If I use the function like this, it will crash:

```
string a = "x^x-SIL+zh=ang@x_x/A:x_x_x/B:x-x-x@x-x&x-x|x/C:2+x+2/D:x_x/E:x+x@x+x&x+x#x+x/F:uj_1/G:x_x/H:x=x^x=x|x/I:1=1/J:7+6-6x^x-SIL+zh=ang@x_x/A:x_x_x/B:x-x-x@x-x&x-x|x/C:2+x+2/D:x_x/E:x+x@x+x&x+x#x+x/F:uj_1/G:x_x/H:x=x^x=x|x/I:1=1/J:7+6-6 x^SIL-zh+ang=ch@2_2/A:x_0_x/B:1-x-3@1-2&1-2|x/C:2+x+2/D:x_x/E:nr+2@1+1&x+x#x+x/F:uj_1/G:x_x/H:2=1^1=6|0/I:1=1/J:7+6-6 SIL^zh-ang+ch=i@3_1/A:x_0_x/B:1-x-3@1-2&1-2|x/C:2+x+2/D:x_x/E:nr+2@1+1&x+x#x+x/F:uj_1/G:x_x/H:2=1^1=6|0/I:1=1/J:7+6-6 zh^ang-ch+i=d@1_2/A:1_0_3/B:2-x-2@2-1&2-1|i/";
string rs = StringPrintf("result=>\n%s;", a.c_str());
```

What is the problem here? and how should I fix it?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: ...you could just use a `stringstream` instead of breaking c++ type safety and setting yourself up for memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you use up the `va_list`:

```
int nsize = vsnprintf(buffer, size, fmt, vl);
```

but later on you try to use the same list `vl` again when it is already at the end:

```
nsize = vsnprintf(buffer, size, fmt, vl)
```

Before doing another `vsnprintf` call you need to start a new list:

```
va_end(vl);
va_start(vl, fmt);
```

Also, to avoid memory errors use `vector` instead of `new char`. In fact you could just resize the output string and write directly into that.

Comment: Technically you should also check the return value of `vsnprintf`, if it is negative then throw an exception. That might have saved you in this case

Comment: it seems in gcc c++ , it won't return -1 in any cases.

Comment: std::string StringPrintf(const char* fmt, ...) {
  int size = 512;
  char* buffer = new char[size];
  va_list vl; 
  va_start(vl, fmt);
  int nsize = vsnprintf(buffer, size, fmt, vl);
  if (size <= nsize) {  //fail delete buffer and try again
    delete[] buffer;
    buffer = 0;
    buffer = new char[nsize + 1];  //+1 for \0
    va_end(vl);
    va_start(vl, fmt);
    nsize = vsnprintf(buffer, nsize + 1, fmt, vl);
  }
  std::string ret(buffer);
  va_end(vl);
  delete[] buffer;
  return ret;
}

Comment: that's the final piece of code, there's no memory leak, right?

Comment: looks OK , could be improved by using `string` or `vector` as container

Comment: another possiblity is to call `vsnprintf` with `NULL, 0` to get the length, then you only need to allocate once

Comment: This is just what I needed. For future explorers -- check out va_copy if you're receiving a va_list already.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is 512 characters long,and you are allocating 512 bytes to the `buffer` in your function, hence the error. Increase the size of buffer.
change this statement

```
char* buffer = new char[size];
```

`vsnprintf()` and its variants silently truncate the string when the buffer is too small but they don't return the actual length of the string so you can't try it again with a longer buffer. They return -1.

Use  `_vscprintf`. This return the number of characters required without actually formatting anything.

Comment: it is not working, the first time, if 512 is enough the code works fine, but, if 512 is not enough, it will go into the "if" part, it will do something unexpected. you may try it out .

Comment: The second vsnprintf() should probably use 'nsize + 1' instead of 'size'. Also you should use std::unique_ptr<char*>, and remove your delete's, which is much safer (if you can use c++11).

Comment: @JackZhang Please debug and check the return value of vsnprintf and also do check the size of buffer after first vsnprintf statement

Comment: the vsnprintf() won't return -1 if the buffer is not long enough, it returns the needed length.

Comment: for example:  string a = "12"; buffer size is 1; fmt = "%s34"; vsnprintf will return 4

Comment: I suggest you should check it first, because -1, is what i am getting, even with your example... Have you tried to check values?

Comment: Almost every implementation returns the number of characters that it would print if the buffer were large enough, excluding the NUL, but Microsoft have do something different and return -1 if the buffer's not big enough - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx).  No point arguing about it without mentioning your OS.

Comment: yes, you are quite right about this!  I use the ubuntu system. when you man vsnprintf, it will show you that it is the first case. Anyway, do you have a good implementation which can work both linux and windows?